# How to resolve replsync.dll DLL load Error? Please see the attached screenshot

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the following error when using Windows 7. I started seeing this error after installing VS 2010 Beta 2.

[image: Win7 Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the file to something else and it stopped. I only use management studio though.